# wxpython ListBox not updating correctly in another frame/class

Tags: python, listbox, wxpython

I am having an issue, getting my List control box to pass the arguments from one class to another. I am using wxpython to create a gui that allows the users to only select files from one directory and then opens it up in a text editor. The issue I am having is that although it will open the file, it will not update the selection. It keeps it the same as the original default selection. Any help on what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

As you can see if I run this using the text editor on my machine it knows the selection and works correctly.

```
import wx
import os
import webbrowser

class list(wx.Frame):

        def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'List Directory', size=(600,400))
                panel=wx.Panel(self)

        kk=os.listdir("/Python/Tutorials/Script")

                self.yard=wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (100,50), (400,120), kk, wx.LB_SINGLE)
            self.PcuRestart=wx.Button(panel, 1, 'Restart', pos=(0, 30), size=(60, -1))
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(panel, self.PcuRestart.GetId(), self.pcurestart)

                self.yard.SetSelection(7)

        def pcurestart(self, event):
        MainWindow().Show()
#       self.sel = self.yard.GetSelection()
#       self.k = self.yard.GetString(self.sel)
#       os.environ['probe1'] = self.k
#       print self.k
#               os.system("open /Python/Tutorials/Script/$probe1")

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, filename='boo.txt'):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(None, size=(400,200))
    self.q = list(parent=None,id=-1)
        self.q.yard.Refresh()
    self.sel = self.q.yard.GetStringSelection()
    self.q.yard.Refresh()
    self.filename = 'MainProgram' 
    w = str(self.sel)
    print w
    self.dirname = '/Python/Tutorials/Script/'
        self.CreateInteriorWindowComponents()
        textfile = open(os.path.join("/Python/Tutorials/Script", w ), 'r')
        self.control.SetValue(textfile.read())
        textfile.close()


    def CreateInteriorWindowComponents(self):
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)


if __name__=='__main__':
        app=wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame=list(parent=None,id=-1)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why would opening another frame change the selection? I can click on different items in the ListBox with no issues. I don't really see the problem. However, you are using an extremely old event binding method. You should be doing something like this instead: self.PcuRestart.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pcurestart). And PySimpleApp is deprecated. You should use wx.App(False)

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that although you can select the different objects in the Listbox, when you click the button, what is happening is that it is always only opening the 7th selection, instead of whichever new one you choose in the list. It feels like when the button is clicked that the new selection is never acknowledged in the MainWindow class. I am still learning wxpython, and I will update the event with the bind, but I am not sure what you meant with the wx.App(False). Thanks for the quick response and help! I really appreciate it. :-)

Comment: wx.PySimpleApp() is deprecated. You're using it at the bottom of your code. It should be app = wx.App(redirect=False). See also my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's some cleaned up code to show one way to make it show multiple text files:

```
import wx
import os

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, dirname):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='List Directory', size=(600,400))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.dirname = dirname

        kk=os.listdir(dirname)

        self.yard=wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (100,50), (400,120), kk, wx.LB_SINGLE)
        self.PcuRestart=wx.Button(panel, 1, 'Show File', pos=(0, 30), size=(60, -1))
        self.PcuRestart.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pcurestart)

        self.yard.SetSelection(7)

    def pcurestart(self, event):

        self.sel = self.yard.GetSelection()
        filename = self.yard.GetString(self.sel)
        SubWindow(self.dirname, filename).Show()

class SubWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, dirname, filename='boo.txt'):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__(None, size=(400,200))
        self.CreateInteriorWindowComponents()

        path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        print path
        with open(path) as textfile:
            data = textfile.read()

        self.control.SetValue(data)
        textfile.close()

    def CreateInteriorWindowComponents(self):
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)


if __name__=='__main__':
    dirname = r'C:\Users\mdriscoll\Downloads'
    app=wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame=MainWindow(dirname)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```